# :before pseudo-class doesn't work with images

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>:before pseudo-class and images</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        img {
            display: block;
            width: 640pt;
        }
        img:before {
            content: "Test";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://andreygromov.name/picture/flower/flower4.jpg" alt="Ваза с цветами" />
</body>
</html>
```

:before will not appear for image, but it does for any div.

Why?

---

Update:
I found this explanation in W3C:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

---

Update 2:

I forget to mention - i need to visualize "alt" attribute of image with CSS.

```
img:before {
    display: block;
    content: attr(alt);
    background-color: #333;
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: With `div:before`, it's kinda like this: `<div><span id="magicalBeforeElement">Test</span>div content</div>`. With `img:before`, I imagine it's difficult to define a sensical interpretation, because an `img` element cannot contain other elements.

Comment: BTW, why are you specifying the width of the image in `pt`? There are very few reasons to use `pt` at all.

Comment: @RoToRa, because different displays have different pixels density. Having all the sizes in pixels, my website will look different on different displays. I need resolution independence.

Comment: Ok, Interesting. I never considered using absolute lengths in that context. I'll have to read up on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the specification you quoted, I guess this is a case where you have to wrap the image in an element and apply `:before` on that.

---

**EDIT:**

Considering, that the `alt` attribute is for alternative text and basically should confer the same information as the image does, wouldn't that mean you are duplicating the information for the user?

How about putting the information you want to display in the `title` attribute of the surrounding element and displaying that?

Example:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .image:before {
    content: attr(title);  
  } 
  .image img {
     display: block;
     width: 640pt;
   }
</style>
<div class="image" title="Information here"><img ... ></div>
```

Comment: on EDIT: i need to show a picture and explanation below it. Having "title" attribute, user will need to hover cursor over wrapper and wait. This is not what i need.

Comment: I meant display the `title` text with `:before` instead of the `alt` text.