# Strange behaviour on img tag with :after pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

I asked a question yesterday about applying an [uneven shadow with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400097/uneven-box-shadow-with-css3-html5), ultimately the end result was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8XN8j/) (which I was really impressed with!)

Unfortunately, when I started trying to use this on images, I end up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qUpZX/) (the shadow doesn't appear at all)

I can't seem to figure out why this happens, I've tried eliminating the alt text (which doesn't help) however giving the img a blank src attribute fixes it (obviously though I don't want to do this!)

All I can think is that it might be something to do with the `content:""` css? I've tried messing with it but get nowhere.

I could use a div to wrap the img, and give that the class, but ultimately I want to avoid this.

Comment: Images and form field elements (input/select/textarea) do not allow before/after pseudo elements like other elements can have.  It's unfortunate, but it is what it is :-(

Comment: Ok, thought something like that might be the case :/ guess I'll just have to use an extra div in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just put the image inside such a div. Will that be acceptable? Like this:

```
<div class="container"><img src="http://intelligentpenguin.co.uk/blank_story.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUpZX/4/

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457825/before-pseudo-class-doest-works-with-images)

Apparently it has to do with the "before" and "after" pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a div around

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://intelligentpenguin.co.uk/blank_story.gif " alt="" />
</div>​
```

and change css like

```
.container img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUpZX/6/)